# Exception: Content Type application/mspd1 was sent to a service expecting application/soap+msbin1

Tags: wcf, exception, configuration, pollingduplexhttpbinding

I have WCF service and Silverlight Client. I use PollingDuplexElement.

On server side I have following configuration.

```
<binding name="DuplexmergencyRegistratorBinding">
   <binaryMessageEncoding/>
   <pollingDuplex maxPendingSessions="2147483647" maxPendingMessagesPerSession="2147483647" inactivityTimeout="02:00:00" serverPollTimeout="00:05:00"/>
   <httpTransport authenticationScheme="Negotiate"/>
 </binding>
```

on Client:

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IEmergencyRegistrator">
  <binaryMessageEncoding/>
  <pollingDuplex duplexMode="MultipleMessagesPerPoll" inactivityTimeout="02:00:00" clientPollTimeout="00:05:00"/>      
  <httpTransport transferMode="StreamedResponse"/>
</binding>
```

I get following error:
***Content Type application/mspd1 was sent to a service expecting application/soap+msbin1.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.***

What else should be configured.
I spent a lot of time but couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have removed client configuration and configured ServiceClient from code.

Comment: would it kill you to publish exact steps and the client config?

Comment: @BoppityBop I don't have access to that code anymore. I regret I haven't attached working sample and more details about my solution.